# BAT: opening X amount of programs/files maximized but also minimized

Tags: batch, batch-file

I currently have this piece of BAT code that opens all files in a folder maximized.

```
for %%i in (C:\Users\Programs\*) do start /max %%i && timeout /t 10
```

What I want to achieve, is for the code to also minimize all the programs after it has opened them in a maximized state. Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps adding this line next will help:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).MinimizeAll()"
```

It will minimize all windows (not just the ones you launched or are maximized).

Comment: Clever workaround. :) +1